# Find the mode of an order statistic

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1 \ldots X_n$ be iid uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Denote by $X_{(k)}$ the $k$-th order statistic in this sample.

> Find the mode of the density of $X_{(k)}$.

Comment: What is $X_{(k)}$? And have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: $X_{(k)}$ is k-th order statistic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)

I tried to do it explicitly, wrote series $\sum\limits_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i} x^{i} (1-x)^{n-i}$ which is probability of $X_{(k)} \leq x$ and tried to differentiate it and find maximum, but it appered to be too difficult, I suppose there is easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track - if you take a derivative of the expression you got for the distribution function, a lot of terms in the sum cancel out, and you end up with
$$f_k(x) = n \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-k} \quad \mbox{ for }x\in[0,1],$$
see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution). This density is already easy to handle.